# Best nginx redirect with regex

Tags: redirect, nginx, debian

How is it best to redirect paths in nginx?

My old url:

```
domain.com/id/username.html
```

New url:

```
domain.com/users/username.id
```

eg. new url: `domain.com/users/math3w-999.9235`

I need to use rewrite, or location /users/ and try_files, or something else?
What solution is the most optimal now? I have a lot of users, threads etc.

Answer (score 1):

The rewrite directive is optimal to capture elements in the original URL that don’t have corresponding NGINX variables, or change or add elements in the path.

Good article about differences is posted on [nginx.com](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/)

For your example try this:

```
rewrite ^/([[:digit:]]+)/(.*)\.html /users/$2.$1 permanent;
```

You can use location or map directive with rewrite rule.